# AngularJs Webpack, moment is not defined

Tags: angularjs, npm, webpack, momentjs

After 2 days trying instantiate "momentjs" library on webpack-based app, I can't see a way to make it. But it is indispensable for this project, so, after making custom loader, resolve aliases and plugins to accomplish my task, nothing happened. This is my module file:

```js
var NavbarController = require('./navbar.controller');
var NavbarComponent = require('./navbar.component');
var moment = require('moment');
require('ng-bs-daterangepicker');

angular
  .module('app.navbar', [])
  .controller('NavbarController', NavbarController)
  .component('esdNavbar', NavbarComponent);// Yeoman hook. Module components. Do not remove this comment
```

In the `webpack.config` i have jquery, jquery-ui and daterangepicker, those works perfectly fine, but the last one needs momentjs.

What is the correct way to import `moment` object to my controller?